# HttpPostedFileBase is null mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-uploading, httppostedfilebase

I have been trying to figure out why my HttpPostedFileBase is returning null. I have looked around at other answers and also followed some tutorials on how to upload an image. The thing is I am still just getting null from HttpPostedFileBase and Request.Files. Is there something I am missing?

My controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase PreviewImageFile)
    {

        //some code//

        if (PreviewImageFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var uploadedImage = new Bitmap(PreviewImageFile.InputStream);
                var width = 368;
                var height = 305;
                var uploadedImageThumb = ImageHelper.CreateThumbnail(uploadedImage, width, height);

                uploadedImageThumb.Save("/path" + id + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                uploadedImageThumb.Dispose();
                uploadedImage.Dispose();

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        //some code here//

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

And my Form from the view

```
                <% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "SaveThemes", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "TestForm" }))
                   {  %>

                        <label for="PreviewImageFile">Perview Image</label>
                        <input type="file" id="PreviewImageFile" name="PreviewImageFile" size="40" value="" />


                //some code here//
                <button type="submit" >save</button>
                <% } %>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code example you have shown. Please provide more details about the HTTP request being made. Use Fiddler or the developer toolbar of your webbrowser to capture the actual request and show it here. HTTP headers + HTTP POST body payload. Also do you have some javascript plugins that might be hijacking the form submit handler?

Comment: Debug your app and check this Request.Files.Count when you post your file. If it works, you can use Request.Files[0]

Comment: Your use of returning `JSON()` at the end of your ActionMethod and the putting an id element on the form leads me to believe you are trying to upload the file using an AJAX method.  Without some special plugins, AJAX file uploads do not work* (yes, there are some HTML 5 methods, but in general its a no go).  Are you using jQuery or some other JavaScript to actually post the form?

Comment: I am using the `.submit()` from jquery to submit the form and some JavaScript to validate the inputs that I am taking in.

Comment: @Themonkey180 - yup, you cannot AJAX submit (meaning using jQuery) a form with a file upload.  You can validate it with jQuery, but the actual form submission needs to be a full page POST to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. There was a AJAX call happen that i did not know of, and it was over riding my calls.